# Is it possible to access to Autodesk Drive using Forge or another API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an Autodesk Drive storage with some folders, and Fusion Team storage. But using Forge API I can access only those items and files, that are located in Fusion Team hub, because Autodesk Drive hub is not shown in response on "GET /project/v1/hubs". Is it possible to access to Autodesk Drive using Forge or another API?

Comment: Hi, it's unsupported currently as know. To provide a more precise answer, I'm double-checking with our engineering team, and will get back to you A.S.A.P. Thanks.

Comment: @EasonKang thats sad, thanks